# Weird scrollTop function behavior - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the css position from fixed to static and viceversa, based on pixel scrolled...
The script works fine as espected, but at the point to change css position, there is a sort of lag.

If i scroll slow till at the point of switch, from the console i see the position switch fast from fixed to static and from static to fixed.

Anyway, look in the snippet, scroll near the end, and see what happen... I'm not able to figure out the reason. Hope in your help! Thanks!

**Open the snipped in fullscreen to see better!**

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    var add_px = $('body').height();
    var px_scroll = scrolled + add_px;
    
    var tot = $(document).height();
    var ftr = $('#footer').css("margin-bottom");
    ftr = ftr.replace('px','');
    ftr = ftr.replace('-','');
    var total = tot - ftr;
    
    if ( px_scroll > total ) {
        $('#act_btns').css({'position':'static'});
    } else {
        $('#act_btns').css({'position':'fixed'});
    }
});
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; margin:0; padding: 0; }

#main_container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#act_btns {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 50px;
}
#act_btns input {
    color: #fff;
    border: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #000;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: -200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 10px 7px 15px 7px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body>
<div id="main_container">

<div style="position:relative;margin:0 auto 20px;width:80%;height:2500px;background:#ccc;"></div>

<div id="act_btns">
<input type="submit" name="save_list" id="save_btn" value="Salva">
<input type="submit" name="reset_list" id="rst_btn" value="Reset">
</div>

<div id="footer"><p id="copyright">Copyright © 2016 - 2021</p></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is: You calculate the `total` value on every change of the scroll position. So when you scroll and change the position of the element from `fixed` to `static` you will add the `height` (60px) to `total`. (This is visible if you `console.log(scrolled, total)`). Because `fixed` position elements do not take up any space.

The most simple fix is to calculate the `total` when the page is loaded. And then, if it doesn't change you're good to go with that height forever. So the only change I did from your code is to move the calculation of `total` outside of the scroll function.

```js
var tot = $(document).height();
var ftr = $('#footer').css("margin-bottom");
ftr = ftr.replace('px','');
ftr = ftr.replace('-','');
var total = tot - ftr;


$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    var add_px = $('body').height();
    var px_scroll = scrolled + add_px;
    
    if ( px_scroll > total ) {
        $('#act_btns').css({'position':'static'});
    } else {
        $('#act_btns').css({'position':'fixed'});
    }
});
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; margin:0; padding: 0; }

#main_container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#act_btns {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 50px;
}
#act_btns input {
    color: #fff;
    border: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #000;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: -200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 10px 7px 15px 7px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body>
<div id="main_container">

<div style="position:relative;margin:0 auto 20px;width:80%;height:2500px;background:#ccc;"></div>

<div id="act_btns">
<input type="submit" name="save_list" id="save_btn" value="Salva">
<input type="submit" name="reset_list" id="rst_btn" value="Reset">
</div>

<div id="footer"><p id="copyright">Copyright © 2016 - 2021 VirtualCode.Net</p></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This could lead to some problems if you are loading images and what not which may take up more space (height) when completely loaded and the calculation already happened. To never face that issue you can wrap the calculation inside

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // add total calculation code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i have not think that relative position add pixels... :( I'm just gonna to test your code on my local website

Comment: Is there a problem, from the console i see a message error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: total is not defined

Seems that i can't use that variable outside the scroll function...

Comment: Sorry a lot, i had the script in the head tags... Now have move to the bottom and everything is working fine! Thanks a lot again! ;)

Comment: @Devilix nice, happy coding!